# My bundler command is failing to load in my Sinatra app deployed in Heroku and thus causes it to crash

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I am trying to successfully deploy an extremely rudimentary Sinatra app to Heroku. I am able to run this app locally. The ruby code itself is incredibly simple:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello World!'
end
```

I added a proper Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'rack'
```

As well as a configuration file:

```rb
require './hello_app'
run SinatraApp
```

This code builds successfully on Heroku:

````bash
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rack
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Using bundler 2.1.4
       Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.2
       Using mustermann 1.1.1
       Using rack 2.2.3
       Using rack-protection 2.1.0
       Using tilt 2.0.10
       Using sinatra 2.1.0
       Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 7 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Bundle completed (0.49s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Detecting rake tasks
###### WARNING:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       
       To declare a Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       
       ```
       ruby "2.6.6"
       ```
       
       For more information see:
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 13.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://arcane-depths-40341.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
````

However when I deploy it and actually visit the site it crashes and the following is displayed in the log:

```bash
2020-12-22T14:04:23.100758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-22T14:04:24.857234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p ${PORT:-5000}`
2020-12-22T14:04:28.910617+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rackup)
2020-12-22T14:04:28.910647+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::Exception: can't find executable rackup for gem rack. rack is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
2020-12-22T14:04:28.910648+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in `block in replace_bin_path'
2020-12-22T14:04:28.910648+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:402:in `block in replace_bin_path'
2020-12-22T14:04:28.910648+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-12-22T14:04:29.001978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-22T14:04:29.106041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-22T18:56:39.441582+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=arcane-depths-40341.herokuapp.com request_id=875e2357-d1f9-4457-ab68-3d6a76bea281 fwd="98.13.129.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My 2 questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do it fix it such that the app successfully loads on Heroku?

Comment: The error says `2020-12-22T14:04:28.910647+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::Exception: can't find executable rackup for gem rack. rack is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?` have you added Rack to the Gemfile?

Comment: You've got `run SinatraApp` rather than `run Sinatra::Application`. That won't work with your current application. The rack gem is also pulled in automatically by Bundler when it resolves the sinatra and thin gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Identified Problems

You have a number of issues, but the largest is that you're attempting to `run SinatraApp` rather than `run Sinatra::Application`. This is most likely what's causing the app to crash, and the correct invocation is in both the Heroku and Sinatra documentation.

Furthermore, the [Sinatra README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) recommends using the thin web server. Heroku [recommends using a Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rack-applications-process-types) that explicitly defines the web server invocation for most Ruby-based apps. Specifically, it says:

> Regardless of the webserver you choose, production apps should always specify the webserver explicitly in the Procfile.

Below, I provide my own suggested configuration for Sinatra apps that's (very slightly) less minimalist than the one provided in the Heroku docs. Start there, then tune it to suit.

### Use a Foreman Procfile to Start Sinatra on Heroku

First, make sure your application's Heroku stack includes the `heroku/ruby` buildpack. Then, use a [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) Procfile to start your Sinatra app using the thin web server. For example:

```rb
# Gemfile

ruby '2.6.6'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'foreman'
```

```rb
# config.ru
require './hello_app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

```
# Procfile

dev: bundle exec rackup
web: APP_ENV=production bundle exec rackup -p "$PORT"
```

You can probably get it working with other configurations, including the [minimalist one suggested by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack#sinatra), but this setup works reliably for a broad number of Sinatra applications on Heroku. Your mileage (and number of errors) with other configurations may vary.

Comment: I have followed the suggestions as provided. I completely edited the config.ru, Gemfile, and added the Procfile. Initially it did not work as I had ruby v2.3.3 however after updating my ruby version it works. This was initially a very frustrating problem, so thank you kindly.