# Unable to deploy my simple Sinatra app to Heroku

Tags: ruby, sinatra

My Sinatra app is really simple.

Config.ru

```
require './hello_app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.6.6"
gem 'sinatra'
```

hello_app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

This app works locally. However, when I try deploying to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
2020-12-27T23:29:11.036031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-27T23:29:12.572800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `APP_ENV=production bundle exec rackup -p "57643"`
2020-12-27T23:29:16.071115+00:00 app[web.1]: [heroku-exec] Starting
2020-12-27T23:29:16.663254+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rackup)
2020-12-27T23:29:16.663275+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::Exception: can't find executable rackup for gem rack. rack is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
2020-12-27T23:29:16.663276+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in `block in replace_bin_path'
2020-12-27T23:29:16.663277+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:402:in `block in replace_bin_path'
2020-12-27T23:29:16.663277+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-12-27T23:29:16.722478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-27T23:29:16.770208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have tried many suggestions offered in other threads like adding a Procfile etc., I get the same error every time. I am a new learner and I have reached a dead end. Any ideas on how I can move forward?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My bundler command is failing to load in my Sinatra app deployed in Heroku and thus causes it to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65414701/my-bundler-command-is-failing-to-load-in-my-sinatra-app-deployed-in-heroku-and-t)

Comment: @AlterLagos I tried all the suggestions there. Didn't help unfortunately; it is the same issue though.

Comment: You may be just missing to add `gem 'rack'` to your Gemfile 
Related error is `Gem::Exception: can't find executable rackup for gem rack. rack is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?`

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem which is now fixed. My app is called Birthday (defined in app.rb as `def class Birthday < Sinatra::Base`).

I have a `config.ru` file that says:

```rb
require_relative "./lib/app.rb"
run Birthday
```

My Gemfile is:

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.7.2"
gem "sinatra"
...
gem "rack"
```

I don't know if the rack gem is necessary, I added it while trying to get the app to run on Heroku. I can run my project locally with `ruby app.rb` or `rackup config.ru`. But it wasn't running correctly on Heroku.
Therefore I added a Procfile as seen in an answer elsewhere, saying:

```rb
dev: bundle exec rackup
web: APP_ENV=production bundle exec rackup -p "$PORT"
```

Your Heroku process reports: `Starting process with command 'APP_ENV=production bundle exec rackup -p "57643"'`, so this might be a similar problem.

The Procfile didn't work, my app didn't load properly. In my Heroku console, I found that I had a choice of two dynos for the project. If I enabled only
`dev bundle exec rackup` the app didn't load at all. If I enabled
`web APP_ENV=production bundle exec rackup -p "$PORT"` only, the page loaded but it just said `GET /`.

It occurred to me that I never set APP_ENV anywhere. So I deleted that part from the Procfile. Now the Heroku dyno lists `web bundle exec rackup -p "$PORT". It worked!